# Concatenation in Drools

Tags: java, drools

I need to concatenate `deptNo` (binding variable) to `loc` (normal variable) and store into `deptFullName` variable. The purpose is to use `deptFullName` for searching in a map of `deptDetail`.

Writing dsl something like (line breaks added fpror better readability):

```
[condition][]Get decision for Depertment{deptName} and location{loc}
             to be paid higher with employee count {count}=
             Company( $deptDetails : deptDetails , $deptNo : deptNo)
             String($deptFullName : ($deptNo+"_"+"{loc}"))
             Company( $deptDetails.containsKey($deptFullName), 
                      $deptDetails.get($deptFullName) != null)
```

But not able to concat since in `String($deptFullName : ($deptNo+"_"+"{loc}"))` binding variable can't be on right side.

Answer (score 0):

Simply repeat the concatenation:

```
[condition][]Get decision for Depertment{deptName} and location{loc}
             to be paid higher with employee count {count}=
             Company( $deptDetails : deptDetails , $deptNo : deptNo,
                      $deptDetails.containsKey($deptNo+"_"+"{loc}"), 
                      $deptDetails.get($deptNo+"_"+"{loc}") != null)
```

It's possible that you can omit containsKey - the test whether the result of a get with the same key is not null should be sufficient.